# Command - binding from DataGridTemplateColumn

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Occerences}" 
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Start index" Binding="{Binding Start}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="End index"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Length"  />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Pattern"  />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Sequence">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Sequence" Command="{Binding SequenceCommand}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Export">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="Export" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>       
</DataGrid> 

<Button Content="Sequence" Command="{Binding SequenceCommand}" />
```

This is not working. How to bind to SequenceCommand (MyViewModel, ICommand SequenceCommand)?

I can't use frameworks (mvvm light tool kit, prism, etc).

Answer (score 5):

The DataContext in `DataTemplate` for CellTemplate will be changed to bind to the current item where the SequenceCommand is not found. You have to set a RelativeSource to the `DataGrid` and set `Path` for `DataContext.SequenceCommand` like this:

```
<Button Content="Sequence" 
        Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid},
        Path=DataContext.SequenceCommand}" />
```

Comment: Don't forget to put `DataContext`, otherwise it will look for `DataGrid.SequenceCommand` which doesn't exist